# Unable to cast object of type ‘System.Web.UI.LiteralControl’ Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error:
Unable to cast object of type ‘System.Web.UI.LiteralControl’ to type ‘System.Web.Controls.TextBox’

I am feeding my Text input box from a querystring in the ASPX page and here is the code:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="GV_Post_ID" runat="server" text='<%# Request.QueryString["Post_ID"] %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

But when I run it, it stops here:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
```

and I get the error above.  Here is the code behind:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DSRConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RCA_Events(Post_ID, Date, Description) VALUES(@Post_ID, @Date, @Description)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((TextBox)GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Please note if I remove the querystring from the ASPX page and then I insert the value manually then it works.  Pls. help.
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is here:

`(TextBox)GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls[0]`

The first control in that cell isn't the `TextBox` you think it is.  Let's assume `GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0]` is safely getting you the row you need.  Do something like this:

```
TextBox myTextBox = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox.Text;
```

That code can be even more safe like this:

```
TextBox myTextBox = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;
if (myTextBox != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myTextBox.Text;
}
else
{
    // Do something here.  Default value for the post id?
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is when you are using Gridviews and you convert **Databound** fields into **ItemTemplates**, and you add for example a textbox to the **EditItemTemplate** and you then add its own ID to that textbox, for example txtProduct, the function **.controls[0]** won't find it, it doesnt know the ID of your textbox, so in this case you will have to provide the ID of the TextBox that you want to target. So instead of using **.Controls[0]** you should use **.FindControl("txtProduct")**. In your case instead of:

```
(TextBox)GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls[0].Text;
```

you should do this:

```
(TextBox)GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("GV_Post_ID").Text;
```