# Getting checkbox value from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I understand the error message but not sure how to correct the problem. I have grid in which I have a check box and I want to get its value, checked or unchecked.

In the gv_RowUpdating, I have the following code that works with other controls such as a text box but not with check box.

```
bool active = ((CheckBox)gvLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Controls[0]).Checked;
```

The error I get is `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'`.

I've come across several examples but none that I saw are going about the same way I am. Examples would include iterating to controls of the gridview or using a `FindControl` construct. In my case the checkbox is present and has a value but the issue is with casting (I think). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first control in that cell isn't the `CheckBox` you think it is. Let's assume `gvLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex]` is safely getting you the row you need. Do something try this

```
CheckBox cxbx  = gvLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBoxIdName") as CheckBox;
bool active=cxbx.Checked;
```

Reffered from : [Unable to cast object of type ‘System.Web.UI.LiteralControl’ Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979100/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-web-ui-literalcontrol-error)

Comment: Okay, these are similar examples I saw, what I don't understand is that I the following code for text boxes and they work with out having to do a `FindControl` like this `string linkText = ((TextBox)gvLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;`. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkb");

    if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkb")).Checked)
    {
       //Your Code
    }
```