# How to cast LiteralControl to LinkButton in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void gvDispMsg_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView hGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        TableHeaderCell tcCellSub1 = new TableHeaderCell();
        tcCellSub1.Controls.Add(lblDDLBlank);
        gvrRow.Cells.Add(tcCellSub1);

        gvDispMsg.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gvrRow);

        LinkButton btnSort;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image;
        //iterate through all the header cells
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            //check if the header cell has any child controls
            if (cell.HasControls())
            {
                //get reference to the button column
                btnSort = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];
                image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                if (ViewState["sortExp"] != null)
                {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in line `btnSort = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];`:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.
```

How can I resolve the error.

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979100/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-web-ui-literalcontrol-error

Comment: If I were doing it without a foreach loop I would do the following 
`btnSort = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[number of your cell].Controls[0];` so where I have `number of your cell` I am wondering if it knows what cell it's actually working on .. can you try playing around with that in the `Quick Watch`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone finds it in a search in the future this is the correct way to cast a link button from a grid view:

```
var btnSort = (LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Controls[1];
```