# Casting Exception in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, web-applications

I have a function:

```
  private void ds_ItemBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemIndex >= 0)
            {
                e.Item.Cells[0].Controls.Add(Utility.GetImage("Delegate"));

                e.Item.Attributes.Add("Description", ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row["DelegateDescription"].ToString());
                string DelegateName = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row["DelegateName"].ToString();

                e.Item.Attributes.Add("DelegateName", ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem)).Row["DelegateName"].ToString());

                ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)(e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked = false;


                if (hDelegates.Value != "")
                {

                    string[] selectedDelegates = hDelegates.Value.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    foreach (string delegate in selectedDelegates)
                    {

                        if (delegate.Equals(delegateName))
                        {
                            count++;
                            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)(e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked = true;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count == dDelegates.Items.Count)
                lblEditCheck.Checked = true;
            else
                lblEditCheck.Checked = false;
        }
```

The UI has a table with each row corresponding to one entry. So, each row has an image, a description, a name.

I am getting an exception in the code at line:

```
((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)(e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked = false;
```

The exception is : `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'.`

Further, `e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0]` is `System.Web.UI.LiteralControl` .

And the the check box markup looks like `<asp:CheckBox ID="lblEditCheck" runat="server" TabIndex="0" Width="30px" CssClass="ColumnHeader" /></td>`

I am stuck on getting this to work for a few days now. Please let  me know if any more info will be useful.

Thanks a lot for your help.

What didn't work:

```
var checkbox = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("lblEditCheck");
checkbox.Checked = false;
```

In this case checkbox is null. And the corresponding exception is thrown.

Comment: [Maybe a similar issue to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979100/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-web-ui-literalcontrol-error)

Comment: @john I edited the question with a way that didn't work. It is quite similar.

Comment: Please show us the html you have

Answer (score 1):

Use IDs of the controls which you want to get and use the `FindControl` to get the `CheckBox`. Also use the `ListViewItemType.DataItem` for data rows as you will get the null for non DataItem rows.

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
    ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)(e.Item.FindControl("lblEditCheck")).Checked = false;
}
```

If you expect the some of row may not have the checkbox control then you can first get the checkbox and then change it Changed status.

```
CheckBox lblEditCheck = e.Item.FindControl("lblEditCheck") as CheckBox;
if(lblEditCheck != null)
     lblEditCheck.Checked = false;
```

Comment: Hi Adil, thanks for the answer. However, I tried e.Item.FindControl("lblEditCheck") and it returns null. There is a checkbox for sure as I can see it in the markup. Any other way that might work. Thanks.

Comment: It should work, did you use FindControl under condition, if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)?   Also add complete related HTML.

Comment: I can't do that as it says Operator == can't be applied to items of type ListViewItem.

Comment: also one silly question: As a result of this exception in my code: The application has a bug that : loads only one row of a data grid. I think, why even one row is loaded correctly.

Comment: It should not give you operator error, did you use ListViewItemType.DataItem? Show me your code on which you get error.